# Link as image, in TD class created by CSS file

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp

I have CakePHP 2.5.2. How to modify cake.generic.CSS ONLY to change default buttons to images icons 16x16px in action class table here:

```
 <td class="actions">
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Payment'), array( 
             'action' => 'add'); ?>
 </td>
```

I can't do this without modificaton of CSS. I have been googling, and can't make anything better than this:

cake.generic.CSS

```
    #button123 {
       background-image: url('../img/image.png');
       display: block;
       margin: 0 auto;
       text-indent: -9999px;
       width: 16px;
       height: 16px;
   }
```

/View/Agreements/index.php :

```
   <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Task'), array( 
                        'controller' => 'tasks', 
                        'action' => 'add',
                         array( 'id' => 'button123')
                 ); ?>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to understand what you're asking, but my guess is you're looking for something like this?:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image('image.png'),
    array('action' => 'add'),
    array('escape' => false)
);
```

It's hard for me to imagine any circumstance where you'd actually be using the cake.generic.css in any final product, so - just don't use it, and write whatever CSSyou want.

Comment: This is an example only. Sure you are right about css. Try to imagine @dave that you have 45 Classes in your project. Each class have index.ctp, edit, view. Try to change all links to picture buttons. The best way is to build picture with css, without touching the ctp files .

Comment: Honestly, @tomas3man,  what you're asking makes no sense.  Might need to try rewriting your question with an example or two.

Comment: Try to understand. Look at file : cake.generic.css. In line 511 is definition of button: `input[type=submit],
.actions ul li a,
.actions a {
 font-weight:normal;
 padding: 4px 8px;
 background: #dcdcdc;
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fefefe), to(#dcdcdc));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dcdcdc);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dcdcdc);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dcdcdc);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dcdcdc);
 background-image: linear-gradient
}`

Comment: @tomas3man Try to understand, there is no clear question in what you're writing.